# Doxygen can't link array and pointer notation between source and header files

Tags: doxygen

I normally declare my functions in header files like this:

```
extern int Finalize( int* /*handle*/, uint8_t* /*tag*/, uint16_t /*taglen*/ );
```

However, when the function is defined in the source file like this:

```
int Finalize( int* handle, uint8_t tag[TAG_SIZE], uint16_t taglen )
```

Doxygen doesn't link the two functions, so the documentation in the header file doesn't import the info from the source file.  Are there any settings that would let it link these two functions properly?

ETA: I didn't think this was a question that would be difficult to understand, but alright.  If you have two files like this:

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"

/** Finalize something somehow. */
int Finalize( int* handle, uint8_t tag[TAG_SIZE], uint16_t taglen )
{
}
```

and main.h:

```
extern int Finalize( int* /*handle*/, uint8_t* /*tag*/, uint16_t /*taglen*/ );
```

The output for main.c is what you'd expect, but the output for main.h is:

```
  <table class="memname">
    <tr>
      <td class="memname"><a class="el" href="globals_8h.html#a2c3e4bb40f36b262a5214e2da2bca9c5">Error</a> Finalize </td>
      <td>(</td>
      <td class="paramtype">int *&#160;</td>
      <td class="paramname">, </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="paramkey"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="paramtype">uint8_t *&#160;</td>
      <td class="paramname">, </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="paramkey"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="paramtype">uint16_t&#160;</td>
      <td class="paramname">&#160;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>)</td>
      <td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

This is obviously because doxygen doesn't see the array notation for the middle parameter in the .c file as being the same as a pointer in the .h file.

Comment: As that code stands at the moment there are no doxygen comments, i.e. nothing starting with `/**`. What are you expecting to see / Can you give us more context please?

Comment: (After your edit) I still don't see any doxygenning of the parameters so I'm not overly surprised doxygen may be confused.  Humour me for a moment and declare the function with `int* handle /**< handle */` etc. and see if that makes a difference.  Also, which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: It does not make a difference.  I'm using version 1.8.1.2 on Windows.